# Django Import Error with URLS and ROOT_URLCONF confusion

Tags: python, django, url

In httpd conf,

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName tweet_search_engine
    DocumentRoot /var/www/microblogsearchengine/twingle
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/microblogsearchengine/twingle>
  SetHandler python-program
  PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
  SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE settings
  PythonOption django.root /var/www/microbloggingsearchengine/twingle
  PythonDebug On
</Directory>
```

Running python `manage.py runserver` and visiting localhost:8000 returns a splash page telling me everything is okay. However when I visit this site through apache, I get an import error with urls.

In my settings.py file I have a line,

`ROOT_URLCONF = 'twingle.urls'`

I'm assuming this is the cause of the error. The project folder contains only 4 files:

`__init__.py manage.py settings.py urls.py`

I tried replacing `twingle.urls` with `urls.py` but then it gave me a different error. What is it I can do to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo in your PythonOption line:
`django.rooti` instead of `django.root`

Furthermore you might have to add something like this inside your Directory section:

```
PythonPath "['/var/www/microbloggingsearchengine','/var/www/microbloggingsearchengine/twingle'] + sys.path"
```

Comment: actually yes that was a typo.. still getting familiar with insert mode in vim :D

Comment: This produces a new error: `ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named settings`

Comment: had a typo myself: /var/www/microbloggingsearchengine.twingle should be of course /var/www/microbloggingsearchengine/twingle

if it still doesnt work please give the following info:#
full path of setttings.py, fullpath of your urls.py and your twingle/urls.py; contents of urls.py and twingle/urls.py as well as the value of ROOT_URLCONF in settings.py